# TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Tensor.__format__

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, tensor

When trying to convert a code written for old PyTorch to 1.9 I get this error:

```
(fashcomp) [jalal@goku fashion-compatibility]$ python main.py --name test_baseline --learned --l2_embed --datadir ../../../data/fashion/
/scratch3/venv/fashcomp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py:310: UserWarning: The use of the transforms.Scale transform is deprecated, please use transforms.Resize instead.
  warnings.warn("The use of the transforms.Scale transform is deprecated, " +
  + Number of params: 3191808
<class 'torch.utils.data.dataloader.DataLoader'>
/scratch3/venv/fashcomp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:718: UserWarning: Named tensors and all their associated APIs are an experimental feature and subject to change. Please do not use them for anything important until they are released as stable. (Triggered internally at  /pytorch/c10/core/TensorImpl.h:1156.)
  return torch.max_pool2d(input, kernel_size, stride, padding, dilation, ceil_mode)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 329, in <module>
    main()    
  File "main.py", line 167, in main
    train(train_loader, tnet, criterion, optimizer, epoch)
  File "main.py", line 240, in train
    print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{}]\t'
  File "/scratch3/venv/fashcomp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 561, in __format__
    return object.__format__(self, format_spec)
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Tensor.__format__
```

Here's the problematic part of the code:

```
if batch_idx % args.log_interval == 0:
    print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{}]\t'
          'Loss: {:.4f} ({:.4f}) \t'
          'Acc: {:.2f}% ({:.2f}%) \t'
          'Emb_Norm: {:.2f} ({:.2f})'.format(
        epoch, batch_idx * num_items, len(train_loader.dataset),
        losses.val, losses.avg, 
        100. * accs.val, 100. * accs.avg, emb_norms.val, emb_norms.avg))
```

I see from [this bug report](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/typeerror-unsupported-format-string-passed-to-tensor-format/62650/4?u=mona_jalal) that, as of two years ago, there was no solution provided to this problem. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this, or an alternative of any sort?

Code is from [here](https://github.com/mvasil/fashion-compatibility).

Comment: I don't see an explicit Tensor. Is `accs.val` still a Tensor? If so, they should be single items, in which case try `accs.val.item()` and do the same for the other `.avg` and `.val`

Answer (score 5):

This error is reproducible if you try to format a `torch.Tensor` in a specific way:

```
>>> print('{:.2f}'.format(torch.rand(1)))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-ece663be5b5c> in <module>()
----> 1 print('{:.2f}'.format(torch.tensor([1])))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/_tensor.py in __format__(self, format_spec)
    559         if self.dim() == 0:
    560             return self.item().__format__(format_spec)
--> 561         return object.__format__(self, format_spec)
    562 
    563     def __ipow__(self, other):  # type: ignore[misc]

TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Tensor.__format__
```

Doing `'{}'.format(torch.tensor(1))` - *i.e.* without any formating rule - will work.

This is because `torch.Tensor` doesn't implement those specific format operations.

---

An easy fix would be to convert the `torch.Tensor` to the appropriate - corresponding - *type* using [`item`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.item.html):

```
>>> print('{:.2f}'.format(torch.rand(1).item()))
0.02
```

You should apply this modification to all `torch.Tensor` involved in your `print` string expression: `losses.val`, `losses.avg`, `accs.val`, `accs.avg`, `emb_norms.val`, and `emb_norms.avg`?

Comment: quick question for you, you know why in vscode when i type .item() it wasn't doing ay autocomplete? losses.val.item()

Comment: I think you meant this? format(
                epoch, batch_idx * num_items, len(train_loader.dataset),
                losses.val.item(), losses.avg.item(), 
                100. * accs.val.item(), 100. * accs.avg.item(), emb_norms.val.item(), emb_norms.avg.item())

Comment: Does it detect the variables as being `torch.Tensor`, I mean does it propose other Tensor methods? Or it's just `item` that is missing?

Comment: i noticed it wasn't suggesting or autocompleting as well when I typed torch.nn.functional (basically functional wasn't shown at all in vscode but worked)

Comment: Yes, you should apply it *per* tensor. The `torch.rand(1).item()` in my answer was just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: oh unfortunately, I got this error. do you know a fix? `File "main.py", line 167, in main
    train(train_loader, tnet, criterion, optimizer, epoch)
  File "main.py", line 251, in train
    losses.val.item(), losses.avg.item(), 
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'item'`

Comment: problem was that losses was already float

Comment: Check which element is a *float*, then remove the `item` call on it accordingly!